# Django in production, can store media file but cannot find it

Tags: django, image, media, pythonanywhere

I have just launched my project into production. I have a functionality where the user can upload their own profile picture. People can upload their pictures, it is even stored in the correct directory. However, **when I try to achieve it I get a 404 not found error**. I am using Pythonanywhere and all pictures are stored at path:

home/[username]/[project_name]/media/profile_picture

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.model):
    ...
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_picture", blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

**profile_page.html**

```
...
    <div class="photo-container">
        {% if profile.profile_picture %}
            <img src="{{ profile.profile_picture.url }}">
        {% else %}
            <img src="{% static 'external_page/assets/img/placeholder.png' %}">
        {% endif %}
    </div>
...
```

When I isolate the tag:

```
{{ profile.profile_picture.url }}
```

I get:

/media/profile_picture/[name_of_image_file].jpg

**Update:**

I suspect that the error lies in the serving of the files and not in me referencing its path. I suspect that since I also get an 404 not found when

I explicitly try to access the url of the media fiels (https://www.website.com/media/profile_picture/[name_of_image_file.jpg]),

whilst I am able to access the respective static files. (https://www.website.com/media/assets/[some_asset])

Although, that is the result of the python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: Please add views that is rendering profile_page.html to get more information about what are you rendering in profile.

Comment: go the admin dashboard, try adding a picture there, and notice the change. Just click on a picture path to see exactly the real path of the pictures. (Do everything in admin dashboard) and let us know

Comment: are you using a nginx in production?

Comment: Adding an image on the admin dashboard yielded the same negative results.

Comment: Yes, nginx is used.

Comment: In pythonanywhere in the web menu you have to add the static paths explicitly.

Comment: Yes! That was it! Post it as an answer and I will green mark it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the URL and directory path to your media files. On the **Webapp** section on pythonanywhere.

[image: How to serve static files on pythonanywhere.]

I can see in your case. Your MEDIA_ROOT is:

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")`

So, in the **Directory** you have to put `/home/username/media` instead of 
`/home/username/media_cdn`.

This is how I got around the problem, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch from

> {{ profile.profile_picture.url }}

to

> {{ profile.profile_picture.path }}

Comment: What version of django are you using ?

Comment: I am using Django 2.07

Comment: then instead of .path or .url try without anything, {{ profile.profile_picture }}

Comment: That did not work either. It produced: /profile_picture/[name_of_image_file].jpg which also is a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, adding {{ MEDIA_URL }} to the src:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ profile.profile_picture.url }}">
```

Comment: That did not work. However, I noticed that the context variable {{ MEDIA_URL }} is not set to anything. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: @Alien13 yes I think so: `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`, or the relative path to you media, it's the same as you configure /static/ path.

Comment: In your settings.py file I mean.

Comment: Yes, I have added that.

Answer (score -2):

You are storing the files in the filesystem of the pythonanywhere instance. I haven't used pythonanywhere but probably the files there aren't persistent. You need to store the media files in a persistent storage like S3. I strongly recomend you to use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to handle this for you. The setup takes a bit of time but it will solve your problems.